# jQuery: Assign CSS only to elements with specific attribute

Tags: jquery, css

I've got a form (using jQueryUI tabs), where I want the text input elements with `readonly="readonly"` to have a CSS value of `border:0;`.  So far I've got (using the jQuery docs):

```
$(":input[type='text'][readonly='readonly']").each(function()
{
    $(this).css('border', '0;');
});
```

Which doesn't do anything at all.  When I add `$(document).ready()` to the above, my jQuery tabs break (but the sliders don't).  If I only have `$(document).ready()` with no content, it's fine.  I think the issue lies within the first line, but I'm not sure.

I don't want to do this with id/class.  If it's possible to do only with CSS, that'd be great, but I can't think of a way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about a simple css

```
input[readonly] { border-width: 0px; }
```

Comment: *sigh* Here I go again, making things 10x harder for myself.  Thanks for the quick (and easy) response.

Comment: Also always fire up firbeug and try out your selectors in the console. Will save you a lot of headaches if you know whether or not your jQuery selectors are actually returning anything.

Answer (score 1):

Plain CSS declaration aside, your `":input[type='text'][readonly='readonly']"` seems to have a stray leading colon `:` which actually designates a pseudoclass (and `input` is a tag name). Also, try removing the trailing `;` in `'0;'` (or use `'0px'` instead).

Answer (score 1):

```
$("input[type='text'][readonly='readonly']").each(function(){
    $(this).css('border', '0');
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tjrV5/1)